# What is wrong with my Text-To-Speech in my CountDownTimer?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Hey all, I'm trying to put text-to-speech in my CountDownTimer. I would like it to say "There are x seconds left" after a certain amount of time. I just started using TextToSpeech and I'm not really sure what I'm doing..

```
    package com.android.countdown;


import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class countdown extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
 CountDownTimer Counter1;
 CountDownTimer Counter2;
 CountDownTimer Counter3;
 int Interval = 1;
 TextToSpeech tts;

    public String formatTime(long millis) {
          String output = "0:00";
          long seconds = millis / 1000;
          long minutes = seconds / 60;

          seconds = seconds % 60;
          minutes = minutes % 60;


          String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
          String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);

          if (seconds < 10)
            secondsD = "0" + seconds;
          if (minutes < 10)
            minutesD = "0" + minutes;

          output = minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
          return output;
        }

   @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);




//Declare Start/Stop timer
 Button btnstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
 Button btnstop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstop);

//Text field to show time left
 final TextView mCounter1TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter1);
 final TextView mCounter2TextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter2);
 final TextView mCounter3TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter3);



//Counter 1
Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(20000 , Interval) {
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
    mCounter1TextField.setText("Seconds left: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
    if (millisUntilFinished == 10000) {
     instantiate();
    }


}

public void onFinish() {
    Counter1.start();  
}
};

//Counter 2
Counter2 = new CountDownTimer(80000 , Interval) {
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mCounter2TextField.setText("Seconds left: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));

 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mCounter2TextField.setText("Finished!");
     Counter2.start();
 }
 };

//Counter 3
Counter3 = new CountDownTimer(3000 , Interval) {
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      mCounter3TextField.setText("Seconds left: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
  }

  public void onFinish() {
    mCounter3TextField.setText("Finished!");
    Counter3.start();
  }
  };


//Start Button
btnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Counter1.start();
  Counter2.start();
  Counter3.start();
   }
});

//Stop Button
btnstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Counter1.cancel();
  Counter2.cancel();
  Counter3.cancel();
  if (tts != null) {
  tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
  }
    }
});
}

   public void instantiate() {
      tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
      tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
         tts.speak("You have 10 seconds remaining", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

   }

 @Override
 public void onInit(int status) {

 }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

Comment: If my answer is incorrect you should post the stacktrace that explains the error you receive in more detail.

Comment: Also note that only the line tts=new TextToSpeech(.. is conditional on the if being true - you have no braces round the other two lines. The other two below always execute. The first time  OnTick runs tts will be null and you'll get a NullPointer Exception. Anyway as McStretch as said that's not the right place to instantiate it.

Comment: @NickT: Good catch, I didn't even notice that the if was there. I merged your answer into mine and credited you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second argument in `tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this)` does not implement `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`.

You need to have `countdown` or another class implement `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`:

```
public class countdown extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
```

Then implement onInit() in said class:

```
void onInit(int status){
   // implementation 
}
```

And finally pass the class that implements OnInitListener into the `TextToSpeech` constructor:

```
// The second 'this' will be replaced with another class if you 
// decide to use a class other than countdown to implement the interface.
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

Check out the [TextToSpeechActivity.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.html) tutorial for a full working example.

**EDIT**

As **NickT** mentioned, you also need to add curly braces to your if statement in onTick:

```
if (millisUntilFinished == 10000) {
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    tts.speak("You have 10 seconds remaining", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
}
```

Else you'll execute `setLanguage` and `speak` always, which will give you a `NullPointerException` unless `millisUntilFinished == 10000` is true.

---

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.html

Comment: Well I added tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this); to my public void OnInit() { because if I keep it where the if (millisUntilFinished == 100000) is at I still get the same error. However the weird thing is that it wont speak the text when there are 10000 milliseconds left. But if I put if (millisUntilFinished < 11000 && millisUntilFinished > 9000) then it will work, but the voice will just keep repeating until i close the emulator.

Comment: So basically right now I have tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this); under my if (millisUntilFinished) == 10000 { procedure. It is telling me: "The constructor new TextToSpeech(new CountDownTimer(){}, new CountDownTimer(){} is undefined."

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't realize that onTick was nested in that object instantiation. This is where spacing really helps in a question :P. You'll need to implement TextToSpeech.OnInitListener in a class and then instantiate an object of that type and pass it in as the second  argument to the constructor.

Comment: I've implemented TextToSpeech.OnInitListener to my countdown class. But I'm not sure how to create the second argument to the constructor.

Comment: I've just uploaded my whole new code to make this easier on the both of us haha. Check out my original post. I made the if statement 'instantiate()'. The problem now is that no speech will come up at 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that doen't need to implement `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` in your activity, meaning a cleaner code (In my opinion), is:

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status){
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            Log.d("myapp", "TextToSpeech enabled");
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to "ask" for tts data. I do it this way:

```
// I have this code inside onCreate(), but you can call it elsewhere.
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, 6);

// Then, in the activity add this code:
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 6) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onInit(int status){
                      if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                          Log.d("myapp", "TextToSpeech prepared");
                      }
                  }
              });
        }
    }
}
```

Is almost the same as `TextToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable()`. I'm going to change it near the future.